# Woman visiting sister who has become plantlike to serve treelike beings

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

The narrator is going to visit her sister who has undergone a procedure to make her more plant than animal, so as to be a student of, and "serve" these wise, sentient giant tree like beings.  The twist is that we realize that what we think of as wise and thoughtful 'beings' end up harboring a potential for aggression and abuse, just like humans. Her sister is suffering abuse from her 'teachers' the trees.

Might be from the *Year's Best Science Fiction* collection.

Comment: Can you give more information as to when you read this story, and other clues to when it was published?

Answer (score 3):

I think this is *Into Greenwood* by Jim Grimsley

It was published in [The Year's Best Science Fiction: Nineteenth Annual Collection](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?254036) and first in *Asimov's Science Fiction, September 2001*

From what I remember of the story, this fits.

It was also put forward as the answer to an [earlier question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/140132/short-story-search-a-man-becomes-physically-dependent-on-a-tree-after-having-hi) (with different genders).